# Assign "back" and "forward" buttons to a keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

My current mouse has a "back" and "forward" button on the thumb-side.

I am looking to buy a different mouse that doesn't have those buttons, therefore I would like to have an application that can assign a keyboard shortcut to these tasks such as:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> = forward button

I do not want it to emulate a "backspace" press, I want the same backward signal that a mouse would send so that it works in OneNote and every other application too.

Does such thing exist? I don't care for a small fee, say 20$ but not something over 50$.

Comment: Usually Alt+Left arrow/Alt+Right arrow works for back/forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) to solve my issue.

The point of all this was to take a Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic mouse and turn the Windows button into a forward page button.

Here is the much complicated script that made it all possible:

```
Rwin::XButton2
```

Basically it turns your right Windows button into a forward page button, but who uses the right Windows button anyways?